# Hibernate Cache and JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, jdbc

Will the Hibernate caching(1st, 2nd, or Query) work when I use JdbcTemplate?

I got to know that the caching is one of the advantage in using ORM instead of traditional JDBC. So, If I got to use Hibernate's JdbcTemplate, still can I enjoy the benefits of hibernate caching?

Comment: There is no Hibernate's JdbcTemplate. You either use the JdbcTemplate for direct JDBC code (in which case you totally bypass Hibernate's API and thus Hibernate's services) or the HibernateTemplate for Hibernate code. There is something unclear in your question, please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're bypassing your hibernate altogether, you have to implement/configure those things yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you use JdbcTemplate you will be bypassing the cache entirely and will thus need to invalidate it.

Comment: HibernateTransactionManager to maintain the cache? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Pascal: I must have mis-read something. Having re-read the HibernateTranscationManager javadoc, it does nothing of the sort. Removed that part from my answer.